# Show to prove that a set is closed using the definition

Tags: general-topology

By usine the définition  I mean prove that $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}, f(x)\neq g(x)\}$ is open in the metric space $(\mathbb{R},|.|)$?
that is $$\forall\  x\in A,\exists\  r>0, B(x,r)\subset A$$

where f and g are two continuous real functions
What I must see?

Comment: $f-g$ is a continuous map, hence $A=f^{-1}(\Bbb R-\{0\})$.

Comment: i know this , just read the title I want to prove it with the direct methods

Comment: That's why I leave it a comment.

Comment: @PolineSandra:  I think you should add that $f,g$ are continuous to the question, because otherwise the conclusion can be wrong.

Comment: yes it is I correct the question

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.  Let
f(x) = x if x is rational and 0 otherwise;
g(x) = x for all x in R.
A, the set of irrationals. is not open.

Comment: The OP has corrected the question, which is pretty unfair to you though...